# Implementation of a signature in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have the following function signature and want to implement a haskell function implementing it.

```
method :: (a -> (a -> b)) -> (a -> b)
```

Even though I tried various approaches to do it I seem to miss a starting point. I think I might be able to do it with feats like (>>=), but I am not really sure about it. Since I am fairly new to haskell I am not even quite sure how output a function instead of a value like Int or Bool.

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions

Comment: Try Djinn, it will make the function.

Comment: Note that this is the type of join for the reader ((->) a) monad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's tackle this using "hole-driven development" a la Agda. We want to define `method` which is, at the highest level, a function. We create functions using lambdas so we can start there and leave ourselves some holes.

```
method = \f     ->     #{1}
```

where we know that `f :: (a -> (a -> b))` and our hole, `#{1} :: (a -> b)`. We need to somehow use `f` to create something of the type of `#{1}`. Since we now *want* another function, `#{1}`, let's use another lambda

```
method = \f     ->     \a      ->     #{2}
```

Now `a :: a` and `#{2} :: b`. We need to generate a `b` using `f` and `a` of types `f :: (a -> (a -> b))` and `a :: a`. Hopefully this is becoming clear, but lets keep breaking it down.

Type notation has the convention that function arrows `(->)` are right associative, so whenever we see `a -> (b -> c)` we can think of it as `a -> b -> c`. Furthermore, we have an equivalence between two argument functions like `a -> b -> c` and functions of pairs `(a, b) -> c`. This equivalence is exactly `curry`/`uncurry`, but it's useful in our case.

Let's rewrite `f` to be the equivalent function `f' :: (a, a) -> b` by having `f' (a, b) = f a b`. Given that we can always use the "diagonal" function `diag :: a -> (a,a)` to create homogenous pairs, we're done. We can use `f'` to create a `b` from any `(a,a)` and we can use `diag` to create a `(a, a)` from any `a`. We want a `b` and we have an `a`.

```
method = \f     ->     \a      ->     f' (diag a)
  where
    f' (a, b) = f a b
    diag a    = (a, a)
```

or

```
method f a = f a a
```

So you might see `method` as *shrinking* a certain more general function to a more specific one acting only on the `diagonals`. A type signature that makes that even more clear uses our `f'` trick:

```
method :: ((a, a) -> b) -> (a -> b)
method f' a = f' (a, a)
```

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning (f <*> g) x = f x (g x), and (f =<< g) x = f (g x) x, so this solution can be written as f <*> id or f =<< id as well.